# jQuery .load() - load content from external page into the same page via link in loaded content

Tags: jquery

i'm loading external contents inside a page with `.load()`.

in my `index.html` i have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#conteudo_mostrar").load("inicial.html");
});
```

and

```
<div id="conteudo_mostrar"></div>
```

so, in my `inicial.html` i have another link to `contact.html`, and when someone clicks that link (contact link inside of `inicial.html`) I need to replace the `inicial.html` to contain `contact.html` inside the same div `#conteudo_mostrar` on the page `index.html`

How to do that??

Comment: Do you need to ADD the contents to the #conteud_mostrar div, or REPLACE the contents? Replace would be simply another `.load`.

Comment: i need to replace the page `inicial.html` to the `contact.html`, but my link to contact is in `inicial.html`

Comment: please clearify your question what are you really trying to do

Comment: @raheelshan ..i'm think i'm clear now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.get()` and suppose you have a link for `contact.html`:

```
<a href="contact.html" id="lnkContact">Contact</a>
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('inicial.html', function(data) {
        $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
    });

    $('#lnkContact').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get((this).attr('href'), function(data) {
            $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

If in case you're going to add more links, you'll just do the same for every `id`. If you have another link, let's say for `gallery.html`:

```
<a href="gallery.html" id="lnkGallery">Gallery</a>
```

You'll just need to append it in your code, just like the one in `lnkContact`, just change it to `lnkGallery`:

```
$('#lnkGallery').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get((this).attr('href'), function(data) {
        $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
    });
});
```

Your whole code will now be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('inicial.html', function(data) {
        $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
    });

    $('#lnkContact').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get((this).attr('href'), function(data) {
            $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
        });
    });

    $('#lnkGallery').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get((this).attr('href'), function(data) {
            $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

And for every other links, you just need to make the same changes. Provided that you have an `id` attribute to distinguish each link.

**A more efficient way by Preston**

Tag each link by `link` class:

```
<a href="contact.html" class="link">Contact</a>
<a href="gallery.html" class="link">Gallery</a>
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('inicial.html', function(data) {
        $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
    });

    $('.link').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get((this).attr('href'), function(data) {
            $('#conteudo_mostrar').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hum.. ok..  so i can replace the `$('#lnkContact')` for `$('.link')` and add this class to all link i need to do that??

Comment: Yes, that actually is the most efficient way. :)

Comment: you can see it in: alsite.com.br/djmariclio on the first page, click on "TESTE"

Comment: the page is replacing the entire page, and dont loaded into `div`

Comment: ops... try now: http://www.alsite.com.br/djmarcilio/

i put some modifications for test...

Comment: if i put some link in the same page as my script. This is working very nice, with my modifications. but, if the link is in loaded page, this open as blank page.

Comment: Yes, you almost got it. Though you're missing a semicolon at: `var h = $(this).attr('href')` line, plus, tag the link you want to reload with `chamadar` class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12867/discussion-between-preston-and-ruel)

Answer (score 2):

REVISION based on question clarifiations:

It's simple enough.  You just need to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to the link class/id.  This binds the link to elements that may not yet exist on the page.  Then, within the bind click event, just load the content.html like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load the initial content
    $("#conteudo_mostrar").load("inicial.html");
    $("#contact_link").live("click", function() {
        $("#conteudo_mostrar").load("contact.html");
    }
});
```

Comment: hum.. ok.. so.. if i have many pages.. with the same case, i need to put all some like you did?? Example: in page contact has link to page gallery, so I need to specify all the links?

Comment: Correct.  Just use the "live" code, with the function to load the appropriate html into the div.